# Check if my dialog box is opened or closed, if opened return true or else return false in javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I want return value as true if my dailog box is open and false if closed in javascript

I am new to javaScript.

```
<div class="bg-light row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="custom-file m-5" id="up">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="fileup" placeholder="h"></label>
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" onclick="fun()" id="fileup"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

please tell is there any function to check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting if the file input dialog is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647113/detecting-if-the-file-input-dialog-is-open)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using 'bootstrap' css framework with jquery.
According to the documentation, there is no direct way to find out the status of a window (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal).
But you can set the desired flag yourself using events

```
$('#exampleModalLive').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  flag = 'window is open';
})
```