# How to see if focus on file picker dialogue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, filepicker, focusout

I have a table and each row has one or more user inputs with a `focusout` event listener attached, that calls a function:

```
function inputFocusOut(event, el) {
     let row = el.closest('tr');
     let curFocus = event.relatedTarget;
     let moveOn = true;
     
     if(focus was on dynamically added row) {
          // I have another way of handling these
          moveOn = false;
     } else if(curFocus) {
          // Check if in same row
          if(in same row) {
               moveOn = false;
          }
     } else if(el.nodeName === 'INPUT' && el.type === 'file') {
          // If focus on file picker, moveOn = false;
     }

     if(moveOn) {
          // Check if values changed and do more stuff if anything did change
     }
}
```

The function works great for everything except `input[type='file']`. When you click to upload a file, the focus is on the file picker dialogue, so the input loses focus, triggering the function.

Is it possible to know when focus is on the file browser window, in which case I don't want to continue with the rest of the logic? The `event.relatedTarget` is undefined when the file picker is open, so I'm not sure what I would check.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647113/detecting-if-the-file-input-dialog-is-open), but the answer talks about putting focus on the input and blurring it, which I'm already doing (albeit with `focuout` instead of `blur`). Haven't been able to find anything helpful, which could mean I'm not use the best search terms.

Any help in `JavaScript`or  `jQuery` would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the overall purpose? What is the variable `moveOn` used for and what should happen when `moveOn` is either true or false?

Comment: @chrwahl, users want a way to make quick edits on records in the table. Each editable element has a ```focus``` event listener attached to know which row is being modified and a ```focusout``` event to check if focus shifts outside off that row. ```moveOn``` is the first check to see if the user is still focusing on the same row. If yes, the logic stops. If not focused on the same row,  the logic checks if anything changed. If it did, AJAX called is made to process the new values. If nothing changed, the logic stops.

Comment: The issue is when you try to upload a file. If you made any edits to other fields, an update is triggered before you finish uploading the file (because focus moved from the file input to the file picker dialogue, which is detected as being outside the row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @chrwahl for pushing me in the right direction. I ended up adding another condition to my `focusout` function specifically for `input[type='file']` that works like a charm. Here's what I ended up doing:

```js
var currentRow = 0;
function inputFocus(el) {
     let thisRow = el.closest('tr');
     currentRow = thisRow.dataset.id;
}

function inputFocusOut(event, el) {
     let thisRow = el.closest('tr');
     let curFocus = event.relatedTarget;
     let updateRecord = true;

     if(currentRow === 0) {
          updateRecord = false;
     } else if(curFocus) {
          if(curFocus.closest('tr').dataset.id === currentRow) {
               updateRecord = false;
          }
     } else if(el.nodeName === 'INPUT' && el.type === 'file') {
          if(thisRow.dataset.id === currentRow) {
               updateRecord = false;
          }
     }

     if(updateRecord) {
          console.log('Check if values changed');
     }
}
```

```html
<table class='table'>
  <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>Input 1</th>
            <th>Input 2</th>
       </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
       <tr data-id='1'>
         <td><input type='text' onfocus='inputFocus(this);' onfocusout='inputFocusOut(event, this);'></td>
         <td><input type='file' onfocus='inputFocus(this);' onfocusout='inputFocusOut(event, this);'></td>
       </tr>
       <tr data-id='2'>
         <td><input type='text' onfocus='inputFocus(this);' onfocusout='inputFocusOut(event, this);'></td>
         <td><input type='file' onfocus='inputFocus(this);' onfocusout='inputFocusOut(event, this);'></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input[file]` has the event `cancel` that you can listen for. So, here I created a function exitHander that handles different events on different input types. The exitHandler is the callback function for both blur, cancel and change. If the target is `input[file]` and the event type is either cancel or change then it's a "blur". When the target is any other input than file it is also a "blur".

```js
var currentrow = null;
const form = document.forms.form01;

form.addEventListener('focus', enterHandler, true);
form.addEventListener('blur', exitHandler, true);
form.addEventListener('cancel', exitHandler, true);
form.addEventListener('change', exitHandler, true);

function enterHandler(e) {
  let row = e.target.closest('tr');
  if (row !== currentrow) {
    currentrow = row;
  }
}

function exitHandler(e) {
  let row = e.target.closest('tr');
  if (e.target.type == 'file' && e.type == 'change' || e.type == 'cancel') {
    console.log('input[file] "blur"');
  } else if (e.target.type != 'file') {
    console.log(`input[${e.type}] "blur"`);
  }
}
```

```css
tr:focus-within {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="r1_checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="r1_text"></td>
      <td><input type="file" name="r1_file"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="r2_checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="r2_text"></td>
      <td><input type="file" name="r2_file"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="r3_checkbox"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="r3_text"></td>
      <td><input type="file" name="r3_file"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I think the ```console.log()``` in the ```else if``` should be ```console.log(`input[${e.target.type}] "blur"`)``` instead? Running the snippet shows ```input[blur] "blur"``` when the checkbox or text box is impacted.

Comment: Regardless, your solution gave me an idea that worked, so thank you for pushing me in the right direction. I'll post it as an answer